# What is connection between AppComponent and @Component in AngularJs 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

File app.component.ts in Example : https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/toh-1/ts/plnkr.html is as below :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{hero.name}} details!</h2>
    <div><label>id: </label>{{hero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label>name: </label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  hero: Hero = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Windstorm'
  };
}
```

Now, we set the value of `title` in AppComponent and it is shown in the template of @Component. So, want to know that how it is possible ?

Answer (score 3):

`@Component()` is a decorator and is applied to the class, member or variable directly following the decorator. Therefore because the `@Component()` decorator is immediately before the `class AppComponent()` it is applied to this class.

The expressions in `template: '...'` are evaluated in the scope of the class they are applied. `title` therefore refers to the `title` field in `AppComponent`

Comment: what if a file has more than one Component ?

Comment: That's possible and should not cause any issues, except if you want to use the class name of a class further down in the same file in a class or variable earlier in that file. For that you would need `forwardRef`. To avoid such situations it's better to only have one class (and therefore component) per file.

Answer (score 0):

As Günter said it's a decorator. An additional thing is that the decorator automatically set some metadata on the associated class with the Reflect Metadata lbrary using `Reflect.defineMetadata`. The metadata corresponds to what you set as parameter of the decorator (of type ComponentMetadata).

When the component is used, Angular2 will look for such annotation to find out how to use / configure the component.